# How to evaluate the following Fourier calculation?

Tags: condensed-matter, fourier-transform, crystals, normal-modes

Let $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{r}$ represent coordinates in Fourier space and real space of a crystal. If there is no translational symmetry in the real space, is it possible to evaluate the following Fourier calculation?

Let $u(\vec{r})$ be the displacement of the particle at $\vec{r}$ and $u(\vec{r}')$ be the the displacement of the particle at $\vec{r'}$ In the Fourier representation, $$u(\vec{r})=\sum_{k}v(\vec{k})\exp(i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r})$$ apart from the normalizing constant $N$.

What is the product of $u(\vec{r})$ and $u(\vec{r}')$, 
$$
u(\vec{r})u(\vec{r}')
=
\sum_{\vec{k},\vec{k'}}v(\vec{k})v(\vec{k'})\exp[i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}+\vec{k}'\cdot\vec{r}')]
$$
if there is no translational symmetry? How do I evaluate this product? Because $\vec{r}'$ is not equal to $\vec{r}+\vec{R}$, as there is there is no translation vector in this system.

Comment: What do you mean by a crystal with no translational symmetry ?

Comment: say, it is amorphous with no regular structure.

Comment: If there is no translational symmetry, then $k$ is continuous and it is not a sum that you have but an integral. Also what do you mean by the normalization constant N ?